# Scrape data from Instagram Activity Tab

Tags: android, ios, web-scraping, instagram, bots

Maybe anyone knows how can I fetch/scrape data from Activity Tab - Following Section where you can see what your friends (those who you follow) like and comment?

> Here's the screenshot of what I mean exactly

[image]

This section seems to be unavailable on Instagram Web and also not mentioned in Instagram official API.

But these guys https://snoopreport.com do it somehow.

For instance, when you start tracking someone's activity, some automatically created Instagram account instantly follows the one you want to track and scrape that info somehow. How is that possible without any API?
Is it possible to create VM's with android emulators or smth to be able to scrape it?

Comment: This is not programming related

Comment: @gilbertsyne hi is there any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have answered your own question. There is no API for it (see docs [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)), it's not possible to scrape content from an iOS app, and you correctly pointed out it's not available on the website. Unfortunately I believe it just can't be done.

Comment: Yeah, and that's exactly what I thought as well, but then I saw this tool here: https://snoopreport.com/en/

These guys did it somehow. Any thoughts?

Comment: I’m not familiar with this, but it looks like they’re just getting information on followers which is available in the API. The original question was specifically about the activity information.

Comment: Steven, thanks, but snoopreport surely gets the info about likes/comments/etc of the specific user. For instance, when you start tracking someone's activity, some automatically created Instagram account instantly follows the one you want to track and scrape that info somehow. How is that possible without any API? Also, maybe it's impossible to scrape IOS, but it's possible to scrape Android, isn't it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about that then. Possibly done by scraping the website. I don't know as much about Android these days but some years ago the only way to scrape stuff from an app was to have a developer unlocked device, but I don't know how that has changed. I'd hope the security model has improved to make it harder, not easier.